# Execute a long running method and return a quick response to UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a long running API which is calling from UI. It will take around 30m to complete.
In this case, I want to send a quick response to the UI and the long running functionality needs to be running as a background process. How can I implement that.

For Eg:

```cs
TestMethod("arg1", "arg2");
private string TestMethod(string arg1, string arg2)
{
     ExucuteLongRunningMethod(arg1, arg2); //execute in background and log the results
     Return "Execution started and check the log for the result"; //Provide this message to UI 
}

private void ExucuteLongRunningMethod(string arg1, string arg2)
{
     //Process code logic here
     //log results
}
```

Tried something like this

```cs
public string TestMethod(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ExucuteLongRunningMethod(arg1, arg2);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return "Execution started and check the log for the result";
}
```

but it looks long running method was not executing

Comment: For what reason do you think that the long running method is not executing? This seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: Are you catching and reporting exceptions in `ExucuteLongRunningMethod()`? If not, they will go unobserved (until perhaps after an unspecified period when they will be seen as `UnobservedTaskException`). In that case you'd need to add exception handing inside that method, or use `Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(x => exceptionHandler(x.Exception), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);` where `exceptionHandler` is a method that can log or otherwise handle an exception.

Comment: Why don't you use Hangfire , you could create a Job and just return result. Job will be running in background.

Comment: Well for starters you should use async calls if you want to do something like this. You can't execute a method and expect your program to know if it should wait or not. 

If you want a quick solution why not set the 'execution started' message first and then start the task you want to execute?

Comment: You may find this resource useful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Comment: .net core document already mentioned the best practice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/best-practices?view=aspnetcore-8.0#complete-long-running-tasks-outside-of-http-requests    background service and azure function might be considered.